# How to update the UIList dynamically from 3D viewport selections

Tags: python

I can see that others have trodden this path ... I tried looking at the solutions and could not find the specific answer I was looking for. I would like to add items to the UIList from the 3D viewport selection, and delete them using a button.

Here is the code which I got from a similar thread. I cobbled a delete button into the code but couldn't get it to work.

========================================

```
import bpy

from bpy.types import PropertyGroup

from bpy.props import (
    CollectionProperty,
    IntProperty,
    BoolProperty,
    StringProperty,
    PointerProperty,
)


class My_UL_custom_list(bpy.types.UIList):

    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname):
        ob = item

        if self.layout_type in {'DEFAULT', 'COMPACT'}:

            layout.prop(ob, "name", text="", emboss=False)


class MY_PT_panel(bpy.types.Panel):

    bl_label = "Collection Manager"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_materials"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Move Out"

    def draw(self, context):

        scene = context.scene
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()
        col.operator("custom.clear_list")
        col.template_list("My_UL_custom_list", "", scene, "objects", scene, "active_object_index")
        
        
# clear button
class Uilist_clearAllItems(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "custom.clear_list"
    bl_label = "Clear List"
    bl_description = "Clear all items in the list"

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        lst = scene.custom
        current_index = scene.custom_index

        if len(lst) > 0:
             # reverse range to remove last item first
            for i in range(len(lst)-1,-1,-1):
                scene.custom.remove(i)
            self.report({'INFO'}, "All items removed")

        else:
            self.report({'INFO'}, "Nothing to remove")   

        return{'FINISHED'}


classes = (My_UL_custom_list, MY_PT_panel, Uilist_clearAllItems)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

    bpy.types.Scene.active_object_index = IntProperty()


def unregister():
    # fill this in.
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify your intention. If you want a list of selected objects your operator should not be affecting the list but instead modifying the `object.select_set` state. Alternatively if you want a separate list that you can add/remove from you likely want to store that in a collection property.

Comment: G'day Ratt, thanks for you quick response, I have since solved the problem. Code posted below. Basically imagine you have 20 default cubes in the 3D port, many of them deeply nested in parent-child relationships, and selecting 5 out of those 20, you want them blitted to a clean list that you can quickly eyeball, say in a UI in the N panel. So that's achieved, except for a minor error when deleting one item from the list (deleting all items works fine). Classic "expected a set, not a NoneType" error. Studying up on that now.

Answer (score 0):

```
import bpy

from bpy.props import (IntProperty,
                       BoolProperty,
                       StringProperty,
                       CollectionProperty)

from bpy.types import (Operator,
                       Panel,
                       PropertyGroup,
                       UIList)

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Operators
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

class ADD_REMOVE_OT_op(Operator):
    """Add and remove"""
    bl_idname = "my_selection.list_action"
    bl_label = "List Actions"
    bl_description = "Move items up and down, add and remove"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    action: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        items=(
            ('REMOVE', "Remove", ""),
            ('ADD', "Add", "")))

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        scn = context.scene
        idx = scn.my_selection_index

        try:
            item = scn.my_selection[idx]
        except IndexError:
            pass
        else:
            if self.action == 'REMOVE':
                context.scene.my_selection_index -= 1
                context.scene.my_selection.remove(idx)
                info = 'Item "%s" removed from list' % (scn.my_selection[idx].name)
                self.report({'INFO'}, info)
                
                

        if self.action == 'ADD':
            if context.object:
                sel_obs = []
                for objs in bpy.context.selected_objects:
                    sel_obs.append(objs.name)
                    sel_objs_len = len(sel_obs) # use 'sel_objs_len' as a counter to iterate the loop
                
                for i in range(sel_objs_len):
                    item = scn.my_selection.add()
                    item.name = sel_obs[i]
                    item.obj_id = i # the number of objects in the list, increment this
                    scn.my_selection_index = i - 1 # tells what position to place it in the list
                
                
                    info = '"%s" added to list' % (item.name)
                    self.report({'INFO'}, info)
                else:
                    self.report({'INFO'}, "Nothing selected in the Viewport")
                    return {'FINISHED'}


class CLEAR_ALL_OT_op(Operator):
    """Clear all items of the list"""
    bl_idname = "my_selection.clear_list"
    bl_label = "Clear List"
    bl_description = "Clear all items of the list"
    bl_options = {'INTERNAL'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return bool(context.scene.my_selection)

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_confirm(self, event)

    def execute(self, context):
        if bool(context.scene.my_selection):
            context.scene.my_selection.clear()
            self.report({'INFO'}, "All items removed")
        else:
            self.report({'INFO'}, "Nothing to remove")
        return{'FINISHED'}


class REMOVE_DUPES_OT_op(Operator):
    """Remove all duplicates"""
    bl_idname = "my_selection.remove_duplicates"
    bl_label = "Remove Duplicates"
    bl_description = "Remove all duplicates"
    bl_options = {'INTERNAL'}

    def find_duplicates(self, context):
        """find all duplicates by name"""
        name_lookup = {}
        for c, i in enumerate(context.scene.my_selection):
            name_lookup.setdefault(i.name, []).append(c)
        duplicates = set()
        for name, indices in name_lookup.items():
            for i in indices[1:]:
                duplicates.add(i)
        return sorted(list(duplicates))

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return bool(context.scene.my_selection)

    def execute(self, context):
        scn = context.scene
        removed_items = []
        # Reverse the list before removing the items
        for i in self.find_duplicates(context)[::-1]:
            scn.my_selection.remove(i)
            removed_items.append(i)
        if removed_items:
            scn.my_selection_index = len(scn.my_selection)-1
            info = ', '.join(map(str, removed_items))
            self.report({'INFO'}, "Removed indices: %s" % (info))
        else:
            self.report({'INFO'}, "No duplicates")
        return{'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_confirm(self, event)


class SELECT_ITEM_S_OT_op(Operator):
    """Select Item(s) in the Viewport"""
    bl_idname = "my_selection.select_items"
    bl_label = "Select Item(s) in Viewport"
    bl_description = "Select Items in the Viewport"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    select_all: BoolProperty(
        default=False,
        name="Select all Items of List",
        options={'SKIP_SAVE'})

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return bool(context.scene.my_selection)

    def execute(self, context):
        scn = context.scene
        idx = scn.my_selection_index

        try:
            item = scn.my_selection[idx]
        except IndexError:
            self.report({'INFO'}, "Nothing selected in the list")
            return{'CANCELLED'}

        obj_error = False
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        if not self.select_all:
            obj = scn.objects.get(scn.my_selection[idx].name, None)
            if not obj: 
                obj_error = True
            else:
                obj.select_set(True)
                info = '"%s" selected in Viewport' % (obj.name)
        else:
            selected_items = []
            unique_objs = set([i.name for i in scn.my_selection])
            for i in unique_objs:
                obj = scn.objects.get(i, None)
                if obj:
                    obj.select_set(True)
                    selected_items.append(obj.name)

            if not selected_items: 
                obj_error = True
            else:
                missing_items = unique_objs.difference(selected_items)
                if not missing_items:
                    info = '"%s" selected in Viewport' \
                        % (', '.join(map(str, selected_items)))
                else:
                    info = 'Missing items: "%s"' \
                        % (', '.join(map(str, missing_items)))
        if obj_error: 
            info = "Nothing to select, object removed from scene"
        self.report({'INFO'}, info)    
        return{'FINISHED'}


# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Drawing
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

class my_selection_UL_items(UIList):
    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname, index):
        split = layout.split(factor=0.95)
        split.label(text=item.name)

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        pass   

class MY_PT_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "New Panel"
    bl_idname = "MY_PT_panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Test Panel"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scn = bpy.context.scene

        rows = 2
        row = layout.row()
        row.template_list("my_selection_UL_items", "", scn, "my_selection", scn, "my_selection_index", rows=rows)

        col = row.column(align=True)
        col.operator("my_selection.list_action", icon='ZOOM_IN', text="").action = 'ADD'
        col.operator("my_selection.list_action", icon='ZOOM_OUT', text="").action = 'REMOVE'
        col.separator()

        row = layout.row()
        col = row.column(align=True)
        row = col.row(align=True)
        row = col.row(align=True)
        row.operator("my_selection.select_items", icon="VIEW3D", text="Select Item")
        row.operator("my_selection.select_items", icon="GROUP", text="Select all Items").select_all = True
        row = col.row(align=True)
        row.operator("my_selection.clear_list", icon="X")
        row.operator("my_selection.remove_duplicates", icon="GHOST_ENABLED")


# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Collection
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

class my_selection_objectCollection(PropertyGroup):
    obj_type: StringProperty()
    obj_id: IntProperty()
    #sel_obs = []
    


# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Register & Unregister
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

classes = (
    ADD_REMOVE_OT_op,
    CLEAR_ALL_OT_op,
    REMOVE_DUPES_OT_op,
    SELECT_ITEM_S_OT_op,
    my_selection_UL_items,
    MY_PT_panel,
    my_selection_objectCollection,
)

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

    # my_selection scene properties
    bpy.types.Scene.my_selection = CollectionProperty(type=my_selection_objectCollection)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_selection_index = IntProperty()


def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)

    del bpy.types.Scene.my_selection
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_selection_index


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Very nice. I've since further improved my code to do pretty much the same. I'm now working on the last stage, which is to take the selected items in the list and unlink them from a collection instance (move them out into the ["Library"]. I've almost got the code working, maybe another days' work. If you know how to do it in the most efficient way to do it, post some code! If I do it in the next day, I'll post mine. It's not a race!

Answer (score 0):

The below code is intended as an alternative to the original poster's solution.

Separate operators provided for:

- Removing active list index item
- Adding active object
- Adding selected objects
- Removing active object from list
- Removing all items in selection from list
- Clearing list

[image]

[image]

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Example UI list",
    "author": "Nezumi",
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "blender": (3, 4, 1),
    "location": "View3D > UI > Example Panel",
    "description": "",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Development",
    "support":"TESTING"
}

import bpy

# items to store in UI list
class EXAMPLE_PG_coll_prop_items(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    obj_ptr: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)
    obj_desc: bpy.props.StringProperty()

# add-on property group
class EXAMPLE_PG_props(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    obj_ptr_act_idx: bpy.props.IntProperty()
    example_list: bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=EXAMPLE_PG_coll_prop_items)

class EXAMPLE_UL_custom_list(bpy.types.UIList):

    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname):
        slot = item
        row = layout.row()
        if self.layout_type in {'DEFAULT', 'COMPACT'}:
            if slot:
                if active_propname == "obj_ptr_act_idx":
                    row.prop(slot.obj_ptr, "name", text="", emboss=False)
                    row.prop(slot, "obj_desc", text="", emboss=False)
            else:
                layout.label(text="", translate=False)
        elif self.layout_type in {'GRID'}:
            layout.alignment = 'CENTER'
            layout.label(text="")

class EXAMPLE_PT_main_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Example Panel"
    bl_idname = "EXAMPLE_PT_main_panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "example panel"

    def draw(self, context):
        example_props = context.window_manager.example_props
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()
        row = col.row()
        is_sortable = len(example_props.example_list) > 1
        rows = 3
        if is_sortable:
            rows = 5
        row.template_list("EXAMPLE_UL_custom_list", "", example_props, "example_list", example_props, "obj_ptr_act_idx", rows=rows)
        col = row.column(align=True)
        if len(example_props.example_list) > 0:
            col.operator("example.remove_item", icon='REMOVE', text="")
        col = layout.column()
        col.operator("example.add_active")
        col.operator("example.add_selected")
        col.operator("example.remove_obj")
        col.operator("example.remove_sel_objs")
        col.operator("example.clear_list")        

class EXAMPLE_OT_clear_list(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "example.clear_list"
    bl_label = "Clear List"
    bl_description = "Clear all items in the list"

    def execute(self, context):
        example_props = context.window_manager.example_props
        if len(example_props.example_list) > 0:
            example_props.example_list.clear()
            self.report({'INFO'}, "All items removed")
        else:
            self.report({'INFO'}, "Nothing to remove")   
        return{'FINISHED'}

class EXAMPLE_OT_remove_active_list_item(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "example.remove_item"
    bl_label = "Remove Item"
    bl_description = "Remove active list item"

    def execute(self, context):
        example_props = context.window_manager.example_props
        if len(example_props.example_list)<1:
            self.report({'INFO'}, f"Empty list nothing to remove")
            return{'FINISHED'}
        my_obj_name = example_props.example_list[example_props.obj_ptr_act_idx].obj_ptr.name
        example_props.example_list.remove(example_props.obj_ptr_act_idx)
        # move list index to last item in list if out of range
        if example_props.obj_ptr_act_idx >= len(example_props.example_list):
            example_props.obj_ptr_act_idx = len(example_props.example_list) - 1
        self.report({'INFO'}, f"Removed {my_obj_name} from list")
        return{'FINISHED'}

class EXAMPLE_OT_remove_active_obj(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "example.remove_obj"
    bl_label = "Remove Active object"
    bl_description = "Remove active object"

    def execute(self, context):
        example_props = context.window_manager.example_props
        if context.object.name in example_props.example_list:
            example_props.obj_ptr_act_idx = [i for i, item in enumerate(example_props.example_list) if item.name == context.object.name][0]
            example_props.example_list.remove(example_props.obj_ptr_act_idx)
        else:
            self.report({'INFO'}, f"{context.object.name} not in list")
        if len(example_props.example_list)<1:
            self.report({'INFO'}, f"Empty list nothing to remove")
            return{'FINISHED'}
        # move list index to last item in list if out of range
        if example_props.obj_ptr_act_idx >= len(example_props.example_list):
            example_props.obj_ptr_act_idx = len(example_props.example_list) - 1
        return{'FINISHED'}

class EXAMPLE_OT_remove_sel_objs(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "example.remove_sel_objs"
    bl_label = "Remove Selection"
    bl_description = "Remove selected objects"

    def execute(self, context):
        example_props = context.window_manager.example_props
        items_to_remove = [obj.name for obj in context.selected_objects]
        for obj_name in items_to_remove:
            if obj_name in example_props.example_list:
                example_props.obj_ptr_act_idx = [i for i, item in enumerate(example_props.example_list) if item.name == obj_name][0]
                example_props.example_list.remove(example_props.obj_ptr_act_idx)
            else:
                self.report({'INFO'}, f"{context.object.name} not in list")
        if len(example_props.example_list)<1:
            self.report({'INFO'}, f"Empty list nothing to remove")
            return{'FINISHED'}
        # move list index to last item in list if out of range
        if example_props.obj_ptr_act_idx >= len(example_props.example_list):
            example_props.obj_ptr_act_idx = len(example_props.example_list) - 1
        return{'FINISHED'}

class EXAMPLE_OT_add_active(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "example.add_active"
    bl_label = "Add Active Object"
    bl_description = "Adds active object to ui list"

    def execute(self, context):
        example_props = context.window_manager.example_props
        obj = context.object
        if obj.name in example_props.example_list:
            self.report({'INFO'}, f"Skipping {obj.name} already in list")
            return{'FINISHED'}
        add_item = example_props.example_list.add()
        add_item.name = obj.name
        add_item.obj_ptr = context.object
        add_item.obj_desc = context.object.type
        # move list index to last item in list
        if example_props.obj_ptr_act_idx < len(example_props.example_list) - 1:
            example_props.obj_ptr_act_idx = len(example_props.example_list) - 1
        self.report({'INFO'}, f"{obj.name} added to list") 
        return{'FINISHED'}

class EXAMPLE_OT_add_selected(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "example.add_selected"
    bl_label = "Add Selected Objects"
    bl_description = "Adds selected objects to ui list"

    def execute(self, context):
        example_props = context.window_manager.example_props
        for obj in context.selected_objects:
            if obj.name in example_props.example_list:
                self.report({'INFO'}, f"Skipping {obj.name} already in list")
                continue
            add_item = example_props.example_list.add()
            add_item.name = obj.name
            add_item.obj_ptr = obj
            add_item.obj_desc = obj.type
            # move list index to last item in list
            if example_props.obj_ptr_act_idx < len(example_props.example_list) - 1:
                example_props.obj_ptr_act_idx = len(example_props.example_list) - 1
            self.report({'INFO'}, f"{obj.name} added to list") 
        return{'FINISHED'}

classes = (
    EXAMPLE_PG_coll_prop_items,
    EXAMPLE_PG_props,
    EXAMPLE_UL_custom_list,
    EXAMPLE_PT_main_panel,
    EXAMPLE_OT_clear_list,
    EXAMPLE_OT_remove_active_list_item,
    EXAMPLE_OT_remove_active_obj,
    EXAMPLE_OT_remove_sel_objs,
    EXAMPLE_OT_add_active,
    EXAMPLE_OT_add_selected,
    )


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.WindowManager.example_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(
        type=EXAMPLE_PG_props)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.example_props

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I completed the code, so you can move multiple objects out of a collection in one go. https://dielenator.gumroad.com/l/iwkezs?_gl=1*1gcnz3b*_ga*MTY0MzA5NjE0Ni4xNjY4NTcxNzYw*_ga_6LJN6D94N6*MTY3Mzk4ODg5Mi4xMi4xLjE2NzM5OTA1ODIuMC4wLjA